# Powershell - Email does not have same format as text despite Out-string

Tags: email, powershell, formatting

Folks,

Googling shows me lots of folks have this problem, however the answers I'm getting do not seem to work for me.  Either that, or I don't understand.

Situation:  I have a script that polls and gives a file count.  It works great and I pipe it to a text file

```
Foreach ($Directory in $Directories) {
    Write-Output "You have $Results files in that folder" | Out-File "C:\Filecheck.txt" -Append
}
```

Filecheck looks great.  It does the above loop 6 times (as I have 6 directories) and it does the carriage returns.

In email, its all jumbled up.  On here, someone suggested I use the out-string, so Ive done this:

```
$body = GC "C:\Filecheck.txt" | Out-string
```

I've also seen

```
$body = GC "C:\Filecheck.txt" -Raw
```

I get the email fine, but again, its still all one line, with no carriage returns.

Anyone have any idea?  I know Im so close.

Comment: Output the results to a file, and attach that file. Then just refer the users to the attached file for details. If you want something prettier convert it to HTML and use the `-BodyAsHTML` switch when you send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Environment] newline. I tested with the code below and the e-mail looked good and with the correct line breaks:

```
$DirectoriesFiles = 2,3,4,5

$newline = [Environment]::NewLine
$body = "List of number of files" + $newline
Foreach ($numOfFiles in $DirectoriesFiles) {
    $body += "You have $numOfFiles files in that folder" + $newline
}

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application  
$Mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "someone"
$Mail.Subject = "some test e-mail"  
$Mail.Body = $body
$Mail.save() #or send
```

For the example's sake I just assumed you have an array with the number of files in the folder, but I think you can understand how to adapt to your context from here. My resulting e-mail looked like this:

> List of number of files
>
> You have 2 files in that folder
>
> You have 3 files in that folder
>
> You have 4 files in that folder
>
> You have 5 files in that folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.  My company email didn't like the format, but I format in html (using 
) and utilize IsBodyHTML tag, it works like a charm!

```
Del "D:\Filecheck.txt"

$Directories = GC "D:\Directory.txt"

Foreach ($Directory in $Directories) {

$Results = (Get-ChildItem $Directory).count

If ($Results -gt 0) {

Write-Output "...You have $Results files stuck in $Directory...<br><br> " | Out-File "D:\Filecheck.txt" -Append

} else {

Write-Output "Phew! We're good, <br><br>" | Out-File "D:\Filecheck.txt" -Append

}

$Results = $null

}



    $body = GC "D:\Filecheck.txt" 


Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue

$SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient
    $SmtpServer = "localhost"
    $SmtpClient.host = "relay.me.local"


$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true


$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)


$msg.From = "TelluRyesFileCheck@me.you"


$msg.To.Add("me@you.org")


$msg.Subject = "Checking if files exist on 9901/2"


$msg.Body = $body 


$SmtpClient.Send($msg)
```